# create-react-app's homepage configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

`create-react-app`'s `homepage` attribute in `package.json` is bit confusing for me.

I want my app to be available at: `http://someip/ipt-ui`

However, when I set: `"homepage": "/ipt-ui"`, my app is available on `http://somip` and is not accessible at `http://someip/ipt-ui`

How do I configure `homepage` to get my app on `http://someip/ipt-ui`?

Comment: In my opinion, package.json config can't do that, you can try react-router and route your app to that url.